# How to save rendered html view files from ExpressJS Routes

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I've built few pages of a static website using `ExpressJS` and `PUG` to get the advantage of the template engine.

But now I need to export all the raw HTML that is being rendered by all `ExpressJS` `Routes`.

Is there any package that can help me to do that? Or I've to write custom command and iterate over all the `Routes` and save the rendered output?

If a custom command is the only way, how do I iterate over all the `routes` and get the rendered output?

Comment: Before answering your question, can you explain _why_ you think you need to do what you describe in your second sentence? Because this feels like it might actually be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395686). After all, if your site builds what is effectively static HTML content, why wouldn't you use a static site generator instead?

Comment: To access rendered html before rendering a view you can use the pug compileFile method.
https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugrenderfilepath-options-callback

You can then write the render to a file using Node's writefile.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any library or resource to achieve what I wanted. But with some of my dirty code, hacks, and packages I was able to export all the routes.

**Note:** Instead of writing a node command to export the htmls, I've added a route to trigger the operations here is the code for the route:

```
app.use('/export_templates', router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  const endpoints = listEndpoints(app);
  const failedEndpoints = [];

  for (const i in endpoints) {
    const endpoint = endpoints[i];

    if (endpoint.path == '/export_templates') {
      continue;
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://'+req.headers.host+''+endpoint.path+'?export=true');
    }
    catch(error) {
      failedEndpoints.push(endpoint.path);
    }
  }

  res.json({
    "status": "succes",
    "message": "Please check templates folder for the latest exported html templates",
    "failed": failedEndpoints
  })
}));
```

Basically this route iterates and makes a request to all the available routes with a `export=true` parameter.

Then inside every route view function a condition checks if the export parameter is available then calls the `exportTemplateFile` function with the `pug` template location and new file name as the function parameter.
If the request doesn't contain `export` parameter the requested route will simply output what template.

An example route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.export) {
    exportTemplateFile('views/index.pug', 'index.html');
  }

  res.render('index.pug');
});
```

And here is the code for 2 util function to complete the export process

```
function createTemplateFile(filename) {
  fs.open(filename,'r',function(err, fd){
    if (err) {
      fs.writeFile(filename, '', function(err) {
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
      });
    }
  });
}

function exportTemplateFile(templateLocation, templateName) {
  const html = pretty(pug.renderFile(templateLocation));

  createTemplateFile('templates/'+templateName);

  var stream = fs.createWriteStream('templates/'+templateName);
  stream.once('open', function (fd) {
    stream.write(html);
    stream.end();
  });
}
```

The `createTemplateFile` function simply creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

The `exportTemplateFile` function saves the HTML in the `html` variable rendered by `pug` and prettifies it with the `pretty` package and then overwrites the new template file.

**Note:** In my case all the `pug` templates were static so I didn't have to pass any context to the `pug.renderFile` function. But if you need any context to be used inside the pug template you can simply pass that with the template location.

Answer (score 0):

Edited version of the same answer.

First of all thank you so much for solving this problem.
I have made some changes to your code as per new errors.

Here is the code with async and await function for ejs users

```
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

//set the templating engine as ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

function createTemplateFile(filename) {
    fs.open(filename,'r',function(err, fd){
      if (err) {
        fs.writeFile(filename, '', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  async function exportTemplateFile(templateLocation, templateName) {
    var html = await ejs.renderFile(templateLocation);
  
    createTemplateFile('templates/'+templateName);
  
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('templates/'+templateName);
    stream.once('open', function (fd) {
      stream.write(`${html}`);
      stream.end();
    });
  }

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('./pages/home')
    exportTemplateFile('views/pages/home.ejs', 'index.html');
    console.log('file rendered and saved successfully')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`)
})
```